# PHP Zend Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type bit

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework3

I use Doctrine DBAL with Zend Famework 3 and I'd like to use BIT(64) field.
I can see following supperted types:
https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.7/Doctrine/DBAL/Types/Type.html
Is it possibility to extend it with BIT field type: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/bit-type.html?

I need use something like permission mask.

Here is simple code:

```
namespace Migrations;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\AbstractMigration;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Schema;

class Version1 extends AbstractMigration {
    /**
     * Upgrades the schema to its newer state.
     * @param Schema $schema
     */
    public function up(Schema $schema) {
        $table = $schema->createTable('user');
        $table->addColumn('id', 'integer', ['autoincrement' => true, 'unsigned' => true]);
        $table->addColumn('bitmask', 'bit??', []);
        $table->setPrimaryKey(['id']);
        $table->addOption('engine', 'InnoDB');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created normal BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED field, use it in php as BIT value and everything works well.